# How to move master to HEAD?

Tags: git

```
* [971f835] (HEAD, original_idea) Now working here. Some comment 9
* [692b673] Some comment 8
* [3ebff62] Reverted to original idea. Some comment 7
| * [72ea01d] (master) Decided it wasn't worth the effort. Some comment 6
| * [985c1ad] Some comment 5
| * [4d7d491] Some comment 4
| * [0c697bb] Branched to try an idea. Some comment 3
|/
* [7280b1f] Some comment 2
* [5c2c6d0] Some comment 1
* [bc7aac6] Initial commit
```

So, `master` got left behind.  Not sure how that happened.  Once I decided I was done with the branch that didn't work out I checked out `[7280b1f]` and continued from there.

How do I fix this?  I this the infamous "detached head" issue?

Does `master` have to be aligned with `HEAD` for optimal health of the repo?

My workflow is super-simple.  This is just managing a single text file.  In the vast majority of cases it's:

```
git add .
git commit -am "Some comment"
```

And that's it.

I decided to try an idea and created a branch. When it didn't work out I checked out the root of that branch and went back to the `git add/commit` routine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: How can I reconcile detached HEAD with master/origin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Is this the infamous "detached head" issue?

No, HEAD is pointing at branch *original_idea*

> Does master have to be aligned with HEAD for optimal health of the
>   repo?

No, *master* is just a conventional name, usually taken to be a branch which is readily buildable and hopefully a working snapshot.

> How do I fix this?

If you have pushed *master* to another repository, you need to merge you changes from *original_idea* into *master*:

```
git checkout master
git merge original_idea
```

Be aware that if there are any conflicting changes you'll need to resolve them.

If you have not yet pushed *master* to another repository, you could delete *master* and recreate it from *original_idea*.  **WARNING:** Everyone who was working on *master* will have to reset their *master* branch.

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

$ git checkout -b experiment_1
Switched to a new branch 'experiment_1'

# Here we are going to delete master.  Should be safe, since experiment_1
# was created from this point on the previous command

$ git branch -d master
Deleted branch master (was 72ea01d).

$ git checkout original_idea 
Switched to branch 'original_idea'

# Now that we checked out the branch HEAD is pointing to, we can recreate master

$ git checkout -b master
Switched to a new branch 'master'
```

Comment: Could I ask you to cover one more case?  Move `master` to `HEAD` while retaining the branch currently named `master` by renaming it `experiment_1` first.  In other words, the structure does not change at all, labels move.  Thanks!

Comment: Which commit in your diagram do you want to be the tip of *master*?

Comment: '72ea01d`, where `master` is right now, would be named `experiment_1`.  Then `master` would move to where `HEAD` is right now, `971f835`.  Thanks!  I am working on understanding this better through a couple of online tutorials.

Comment: Try to follow these commands now.  Surely you've backed up your whole repo to experiment, if not you should do it now.  There are many ways of "moving branches", and [deleting a branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#_options) with `branch -d <branchname>` is just one of them, but when I was learning git I used to do it like this.

Comment: Yes, I backup my repo before trying anything.  I don't trust my Git Kung Fu yet. I'll try this later today. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  Worked very well and gave me a better understanding of `master`.

Comment: what does original_idea denotes here?is it the head or origin/master

Comment: I don't understand why I need to merge anything. I have the same situation and I just want master to be on commit 971, I don't care about anything else and I don't want to go and manually resolve all these conflicts. There must be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: You need to merge to prevent rewriting history.  If you know exactly what you are doing you can run `git reset --hard <commit>` with master checked out.

Answer (score 64):

If `git branch` shows that your current branch is original_idea, that wouldn't be a [detached HEAD situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

But in any case, if you want your master to reflect your "current commit" (which is [what HEAD means in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309)):

```
git branch -f master HEAD
git checkout master
```

You would find other alternatives in "[How to I “move” my commits from “no branch” to an actual branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8953206/6309)".

> The problem with this is that it makes the entire branch currently ending at master disappear.

Then all you need to do is:

- make sure HEAD is referenced by a branch (like `original_idea` on your schema)
- rebase that branch on top of master:

That would mean:

```
git checkout original_idea
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge original_idea
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it makes the entire branch currently ending at `master` disappear.  Am I missing something?

Comment: what does original_idea denotes here?is it the head or origin/master

Comment: @prasanthMurugan the branch you want to replay on top of master, before making master HEAD point to this branch through a fast-forward merge.

Comment: thanks for the reply,i created a new branch and solved this issu