# Git origin master does not follow HEAD after commit

Tags: git, github

I made a new branch a while back and now my git origin and master don't follow my HEAD.

Before this commit all of the following were on the current commit `(HEAD -> BranchName), origin/master, origin/HEAD, origin, master, HEAD` but after my commit on `HEAD -> BranchName` moved to the new commit. How do I resolve this for future commits and link all this together? This causes an issue when I push origin master to my repo because they are still on a previous commit.

Comment: Remote branches don’t automatically follow when you commit changes locally. That’s what pushing is for. If that doesn’t help, please show an output of git log.

Answer (score 2):

This is working as expected. When you make a commit locally, only your local branch will advance to the new commit. In your case `origin/BranchName` is there to mimic what is on the server; since you have not pushed yet, the server does not have your changes. After you do a `git push`, `origin/BranchName` will point to the same commit as `BranchName`.

Note that neither `master` nor `origin/master` will move, however, since you are not on that branch. If you want `master` to have the changes you made, you would need to merge `BranchName` into `master`.

Comment: I have branches, but immediately before my commit, I am on the "master" branch but I still leave the master behind and the HEAD of the new commit is detached. To get around this, I have been deleting the master branch and then recreating it on my current commit (according to this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570242/how-to-move-master-to-head). I would prefer master move with my commit if I'm already on master when I commit. Is that possible or working as expected?

Comment: @MrMas, If your commit does not move `master` forward, then you were not on `master` when you made your commit, i.e. your `head` was already detached. Perhaps you were on `origin/master` instead?

Comment: Though I may be mistaken, I'm comfortable saying that what you say is not consistent with my experience. I did a couple commits. Then I checked out "master" and merged to the later commits. This "fast-forward" operation seems to have fixed things. I couldn't merge to master (it always told me it was up-to-date) but the reverse did the trick.

Comment: @MrMas: Hmm, that is really odd. So before you do your commits, `git status` shows that you are on `master`? After a commit, which branch does `git status` show you are on? The behavior you describe would match being in a 'detached head' state before you made your commits, not just after.

Comment: The short answer is that I wasn't actually checked out to "master". I'm still sort of new to Git (I'm more familiar with Hg) and although the commit I was on was named master, I did not check out "master" after going to a detached state. I did not appreciate that just setting a commit to a branch name (in this case, "master") doesn't automatically mean I'm checked out to that branch.