# Failure to push to remote repo in Git

Tags: git, repository, push, git-remote

I do commits into the local repo and it works fine. 
But when I push to the remote repo it fails:

```
$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

Linux writes '**Everything up-to-date**' but in remote repo on github (successfully plugged in with SSH keys) there is only 11 days old stuff. 
What's wrong?

## Update

here is the previous output after commit (ci = "commit -a")

```
$ git ci
[detached HEAD 5b42c77] updated with financial report to calculate for exact contractor and some with table layout for _analogs.php
 12 files changed, 3071 insertions(+), 110 deletions(-)
 rewrite htdocs/protected/controllers/FinancialreportController.php (61%)
$ git push origin master 5b42c77
fatal: 5b42c77 cannot be resolved to branch.
$ git push master 5b42c77
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
$ git push origin 5b42c77
fatal: 5b42c77 cannot be resolved to branch.
$ git push 5b42c77
fatal: '5b42c77' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

## Update 2

```
$ git checkout master
M   htdocs/protected/runtime/application.log
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 28 commits.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309) situation, by checkout the result of `git branch` and `git status`.

A detached HEAD wouldn't be pushed, which would explain the "`Everything up-to-date`" message.

If it is, see "[How to move master to HEAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26570455/6309)" for master:

```
git branch -f master HEAD
git checkout master
```

Or see other suggestions at "[How to I “move” my commits from “no branch” to an actual branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8953206/6309)".

Considering that you are pushing explicitly master (`git push origin master`), you wouldn't need `git checkout master`.

But if you want to do other commits on top of master, then it is important that your current branch be master (and not directly a commit like before, as a "detached HEAD").
Hence the `git checkout master`.

Comment: May i ask you of how to attach the HEAD to my master branch on server?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin first, are you in a detached HEAD locally?

Comment: thank you. I've followed your suggestion, but what does it mean : `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 28 commits.` Does it mean in remote repo are still the old staff and i need to push again?

Comment: why is `git checkout master` needed if i do not want to get old versions from remote but push present from local repo into remote?

Comment: A git push is still needed here.

Comment: thank you. I've done it. But still what `git checkout master` does in this context?

Comment: *detached HEAD* means that your *HEAD* currently points **directly** on a commit. Usually your *HEAD* should point on a branch which in turn points on a commit. `git branch -f master HEAD` ensures that *master* now correctly points at your most current commit while `git checkout master` updates *HEAD* to point at *master* instead of directly at a commit. All further commits will be made on master.

Comment: To get a better understanding what exactly branching in git does you can take a look at the [Git Branching](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) chapter of the gitpro book.